# Google pagespeed image cache

Tags: google-analytics

At the moment i have a magento webshop running and i'm optimizing the website and theme so everything runs smooth and we can get a good score on google, GTmetrix, ...

When i do a run on our website (www.goedkoperfietsen.be) through google pagespeed i always get the "resize images" flag as high priority.
The thing is that all images on the website are optmized  with a file-optimizer. But when i track the images that need to be resized according to google it are always the product images genarted in the cache...

I hope the description is clear enough...
Does anyone has the same problem or anny idea how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How large (in pixels) are the product images?

Comment: example image size: 500px × 350px

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goedkoperfietsen.be&tab=desktop

Comment: Would it be sufficient to edit the following:

app\design\frontend\default\your_theme_number\template\catalog\product and open the list.phtml file.

In about line 96 :
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(242); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>

Comment: Or would it be better to resize all the images to 370x370 and upload them seperatly for the "small image"??

Answer (score 1):

Although you may have optimised the images you uploaded to each product, Magento only uses these images as a basis to create it's own resized product images which are the ones you see on the frontend.  This is why pagespeed is recommending you optimise images - because these cached resized images are not optimised.

Although where possible following the advice tools like pagespeed give is a good idea, the pointers are not always applicable to every site.  Short of altering core functionality to apply compression to generated cached images, a Magento stores product images is one such case.

Bear in mind that the only thing that compressing images is going to do is reduce the amount of data that's needs to be transferred for your page to load fully, much more of a concern in your case is the number of assets per page - around 150, the vast majority of which are images.  This is going to be slowing the time it takes for your page to load entirely much more than the amount of data that needs to be transferred.  You should really look at drastically reducing the image count and you can do this by combining images to create sprites, and making better use of CSS3 styles to replace images where you can (i.e. buttons, circular icons etc etc).

If you can reduce the number of assets per page to less than 60 you will see a definite benefit, 30 or less and load times will be reduced dramatically.  Finally if you can't reduce the number of images by this amount you should look at using at least one CDN to serve your images.

If you are interested in some more detail around what I have put here have a look at our [blog post](http://husseycoding.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/speeding-up-magento.html) on improving Magento performance, you may also want to use our [performance profiler](http://store.husseycoding.co.uk/profiler/) to get some specific advice on improving the performance of your store.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jonathans answer however you could still get subtle improvements from tweaking the image compression.

The grunt work of Magentos image compression is done in /lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php to modify this process you can copy the file to you local namespace, e.g /app/code/local/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php, and make necessary adjustments there.

For example I have made my cached images progressive by adding the following code around line 143 (magento ce 1.9):

```
// make jpegs progressive
$interlaceIt = 0;
if ($this->_fileType == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    $interlaceIt = imageinterlace($this->_imageHandler, 1);
}
```

The quality of the compression is stored in the _quality variable of `Varien_Image_Adapter_Abstract` which the Gd2 class extends. You could hard code it in the Gd2 adapter but a better solution would be to pass it in from your consuming code.

For products the quality is passed in from the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image::getImageProcessor` function which is stored in the _quality variable of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image`, this variable is set from `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::setQuality`. So you could pass it in from your template layer, e.g in catalog/product/list.phtml

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->setQuality(70)->resize(200, 200);
```

Comment: I cant find anything for 1.7.2 version. What method are you updating with these lines?

Comment: You mean the helper? That can be used anywhere in your templates but it will most likely be in your product list templates. E.g catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: No im trying to put that line into 1.7 CE

// make jpegs progressive
$interlaceIt = 0;
if ($this->_fileType == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    $interlaceIt = imageinterlace($this->_imageHandler, 1);
}

unfortunately 1.7 CE doesnt have that line 143. So I'm wondering if you have any suggestions for 1.7 CE

Comment: Can you give a little more detail where/how to add the code? I see options bu am not certain where to add it??

Comment: $functionParameters = array();
        $functionParameters[] = $this->_imageHandler;
        $functionParameters[] = $fileName;
        // set quality param for JPG file type
        if (!is_null($this->quality()) && $this->_fileType == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
        {
            $functionParameters[] = $this->quality();
        }  <<<-===== ADD IT AFTER THIS?